# Cell change in Telerik MVC extension Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm working on MVC telerik extension grid. How I can show the [Total Amount] when 
user enter [Amount], [No of Time] and move into next cell of Grid. Actually I don't know how I can call grid-cell-change event. Please find the following code.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<HMSystem.UI.Models.PatientBillViewModel>() {
  .Name("grdAdEitPatientService")                    
  .Columns().....
  .ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("on_Edit").OnRowDataBound("on_RowDataBound"))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify "Total amount" before save the record you must include a Jquery in the OnEdit that make the modification when you keypress on "Amount" or "No of Time".

Anyway y recommend you to exclude Total Amount from edit and show it after save.
You can create a virtual property in the model:

```
public virtual decimal TotalAmount
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Amount * this.NoOfTime;
            }
        }
```